# How to SELECT fields dynamically (LOOP) in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, sequence

I'm at work and need to SUM specific value by hour. Lets say a shift is 10 hours, I want to be able to loop and do the following pseudo code in PLSQL:

```
For (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    SUM( DB.Sales) AS Hour#i
    FROM
         DB
    WHERE DB.sale_Time BETWEEN 
    DB.Shift_Start_Time + i AND
    DB.Shift_Start_Time + (i+1)
}
```

It should return a table with 11 columns, one for the time of the shift and  each of the other columns sums the sales of an hour in the 10 hours shift, and each will be named after the hour it represents.
Basically I want to use it for other purposes, as my work has nothing to do with sales, where "i" can be as big as 1000 so I'm looking for a generic solution to my problem.

Again, I am using PLSQL.

Help will be very appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Anybody? (I wrote some comments under Gordon's answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on my original demands and found a nice and simple way to loop through the hours using:

SELECT
             db.shift_start_time,
             T1.n AS Hour,
             SUM(db.sales) AS Hourly_Sales 
FROM
             db,
             (SELECT  n  FROM
             (SELECT rownum n FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10) WHERE n > 0) T1
WHERE 
             db.sale_time BETWEEN db.shift_start_time+(T1.n - 1)/24   AND  db.shift_start_time + (T1.n)/24 
GROUP BY 
             db.shift_start_time,
             T1.n
ORDER BY 
             db.shift_start_time,
             T1.n

It also solved my problem where hours are not rounded. If a shift starts at 9:45 it will work as expected and not round it to 9 or 10.

Only issue I have with this solution is that there is a separate row for each hour.. nevertheless , it's still the best solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the analytic functions in Oracle.  First, I aggregate the sales data by hour, since that seems to be the unit you want, and then sum up the hours using the analytic functions with a windowing clause:

```
select db.shift_start_time,
       sum(db.sales) over (partition by null order by db.sale_time
                           range between current_row and <i> following)
from (select trunc(shift_start_time*24)/24 as thehour, sum(sales) as sales
      from DB
      group by trunc(shift_start_time*24)/24
     ) db
```

Note that this assumes that there are sales for every hour.

Comment: I will try it on Wednesday, will update if it worked for me. Thank you for the response.

Comment: The idea is correct (and thank you for it!) but not exactly what I was looking for. I will try to further explain:
1. I need a separate column for every SUM. Each shift needs to have exactly 1 row. shift_start_time,sum1,sum2,sum3.....
2. A shift does not necessarily start at a round hour. i.e , it can start at 9:15 and then it will need to sum 9:15-10:15 AS SUM1, 10:15-11:15 AS SUM2 etc...
3. A bit silly, buy my shift_start_time is of a  DATETIME type. How do I convert it so rows like "trunc(shift_start_time*24)/24" will be able read it correctly?

more...

Comment: 4. Is "range between current_row and <i> following" the correct syntax or a pseudo? what does <i> do ?
I hope I made it clearer.

Thank you very much! I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: BTW, nice reviews on your book!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cursor, looping over each element. The key is to group by the hour you're interested in.

```
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (
        SELECT TRUNC( DB.sale_Time, 'HH' ) AS start_time, 
               SUM( db.sales ) INTO mysum
          FROM db
         GROUP BY TRUNC( DB.sale_Time, 'HH' )
    ) LOOP

        /* Do loop stuff here */

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, will try it on Wednesday.